# How to get the part of string fitted in a rectangle layout by text renderer

Tags: c#, winforms, text-rendering

I am trying to draw a string on a bitmap, but if the text is too long, part of the text may be clipped by text renderer. If I can find which part of text was written I can write the rest of it on another bitmap.

Is there any text rendering function in C# so it gets a text and a proposed layout rectangle and returns the amount of string written (fitted) in the layout rectangle?

```
string fittedString = TextRenderer.DrawText(graphics, text, rectangle);
```

If no, what is the easiest way to accomplish it?

Comment: Is this WPF or WinForms project?

Comment: @Dialecticus Winform, I mentioned it in tags, however I don't think there is a difference

Comment: Why don't you simply put a Panel and a Label inside of it?

Answer (score 1):

Not one that I know of, but you can get an approximate by calling `MeasureText()` on each character of your string in a loop and sum up returned widths in a variable say `W`. When your sum exceeds the width of your target rectangle, you simply pick max value char height of that line in a separate variable say `H`. Upon reaching the end of each line you add the max value of height of current line in `H`.

You keep doing this until the value of `H` exceeds your target rectangle's height. That is simply the number of chars that fit in your rectangle.

Something like this (written by hand, plz adjust):

```
int HowManyChars(Graphics g, Font font, string text, Rectangle r)
{
    float W=0, H=0, MaxH=0;

    int i=0;

    for(i=0; i< text.Length; i++)
    {
        var sz = g.MeasureString(text[i].ToString(), font);
        W+= sz.Width;

       if(W > r.Width) 
       {
           W=sz.Width;
           H+=MaxH;
           MaxH = 0;
           if(H>r.Height) break;
       }
       else
       {
           if(sz.Height > MaxH) MaxH = sz.Height;
       }
    }

    return i;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems a promising solution!

Comment: Thank you very much, couldn't you determine the proposed layout to `MeasureString` and somehow check if it was written successfully or not?

Comment: @Ahmad: No I'm afraid. You won't be able to get that information out of `DrawText()` call. BTW, if you need that level of precision on the text layout, you'd better be off writing each character yourself (using code similar to the one I wrote above and calling `DrawString()` instead of `MeasureString()`). However beware of the dragons out there. You'll need to take care of overhanging characters, kerning, black-box fitting and what not if you need precise control.

Comment: @Ahmad: Has been quite some time since I worked with text-rendering using `Graphics`, so it took me a while to refresh my memories. I just recalled that there is a built-in function that might do exactly what you're looking for: try using [Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurecharacterranges%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It can take a string and return layout information about each character in an array of `Region` objects.

Comment: Based on your original idea I wrote a different function with a different approach posted here

Answer (score 0):

`TextRenderer.MeasureText(...)` method returns a `Size` value which determines the size needed to draw a text. However,  this method requires that the text is drawn on a single line.  `TextFormatFlags.WordBreak` option makes it to wrap the text in a proposed layout.

We set the width of the proposed layout to the target rectangle width and in a loop measure the size of a substring of the main text rendered in this layout. if the `size.Height` returned by the method exceeds the height of our target rectangle, then we stop and return the index.

```
    int HowManyChars(Font font, string text, Rectangle r)
    {
        int i = 0;
        for (; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            string str = text.Substring(0, i);
            var size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(str, font, 
new Size(r.Width, 0), TextFormatFlags.WordBreak);


            if (size.Height > r.Height)
                break;

        }
        return i;
    }
```